# Python Snowball Document Term Matrix: TypeError: 'RussianStemmer' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Прошу вашей помощи. Где-то в коде у меня какая-то глупая ошибка. Переучиваюсь с R и потому часто путаю логику и названия. 
Итак Anaconda 3, Python 3.6, Виртуальная среда.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shorttext
import csv
import Stemmer
import spacy
import re

from nltk.stem.snowball import RussianStemmer
stemmer = RussianStemmer()

pipeline = [lambda s: re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', s),
            lambda s: re.sub('[\d]', '', s),
            lambda s: s.lower(),
            lambda s: ' '.join(map(stemmer, shorttext.utils.tokenize(s)))
  ]
txtpreproceesor = shorttext.utils.text_preprocessor(pipeline)
csv.field_size_limit(100000000)#очень большие куски текста в каждой строке
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Результат.csv',sep = ';',encoding="UTF-8", 
engine='python')
df.columns = ['Num', 'Link','Text','State','All']
docids = list(df['Link'])  
corpus = [txtpreproceesor(Text).split(' ') for Text in df['Text']]
>>>TypeError: 'RussianStemmer' object is not callable
```

Какая-то примитивная ошибка, но не могу понять где. Буду очень благодарна за помощь и совет.

[image: Внешний вид df после загрузки:]

Comment: <class 'abc.ABCMeta'> Спасибо.

Comment: print(type(RussianStemmer)) >>>NameError: name 'RussianStemmer' is not defined  print(repr(RussianStemmer)) >>>NameError: name 'RussianStemmer' is not defined

Comment: На отладку похоже, да, весьма. Извиняюсь - переезжали пока комп пересобрала, пока запустила. весь темп отладки потерян))

Comment: `<class 'nltk.stem.snowball.RussianStemmer'>` &`<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>`

Comment: Удалил свои предыдущие комментарии, т.к. они были не в теме и прошу ваши ответы по комментариями тоже удалить. Надо было вас попросить полный стек приложить, т.к. ошибка была в `lambda s: ' '.join(map(stemmer, shorttext.utils.tokenize(s)))` из-за того что в map передавался stemmer. Т.е. в том коде вызывался `stemmer()`

Comment: А какой метод из `stemmer` нужно было дергаться для каждого токена из `s`? Мб, вам нужно было это: `lambda s: ' '.join(map(stemmer.stem, shorttext.utils.tokenize(s)))` т.е. для каждого токена будет вызван метод `stem` у объекта stemmer?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменил код в `pipeline` т.к. в нем неявно объект `stemmer` вызывался как метод.

Теперь в том месте вызывается метод [stem](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.snowball.RussianStemmer.stem):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shorttext
import csv
import Stemmer
import spacy
import re

from nltk.stem.snowball import RussianStemmer
stemmer = RussianStemmer()

pipeline = [
    lambda s: re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', s),
    lambda s: re.sub('[\d]', '', s),
    lambda s: s.lower(),
    lambda s: ' '.join(map(stemmer.stem, shorttext.utils.tokenize(s)))
]
txtpreproceesor = shorttext.utils.text_preprocessor(pipeline)
csv.field_size_limit(100000000)#очень большие куски текста в каждой строке
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Результат.csv',sep = ';',encoding="UTF-8", engine='python')
df.columns = ['Num', 'Link','Text','State','All']
docids = list(df['Link'])  
corpus = [txtpreproceesor(Text).split(' ') for Text in df['Text']]
```

Comment: Спасибо. Эта ошибка ушла. Появилась другая...но это уже, наверное, в чат.

Comment: @Mar'yaMazaeva, нифигасе, акелла не промахнулся :) рад что с этим помог. А что за другая ошибка? Вы можете создать еще вопрос и его задать по поводу той ошибки либо давайте ошибку сюда -- если она простая

Comment: Пардон, завалили задачами другими. Ошибка была `re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', (s))` хотел str `re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', str(s))`, теперь пайплайн пашет.

Comment: @Mar'yaMazaeva, лучше поздно, чем... :)

Comment: продолжение тут, если интересно [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/954995/%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-stopwords]