# Игнорируется список StopWords

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, nltk

Anaconda 3, Python 3.6, Виртуальная среда.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shorttext
import csv
import Stemmer
import spacy
from nltk.stem.snowball import RussianStemmer
stemmer = RussianStemmer()
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopWords = stopwords.words('russian')

pipeline = [lambda s: re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', str(s)),
            lambda s: re.sub('[\d]', '', s),
            lambda s: s.lower(),
            lambda s: ' '.join(map(stemmer.stem, 
shorttext.utils.tokenize(s)))    
]

txtpreproceesor = shorttext.utils.text_preprocessor(pipeline)
csv.field_size_limit(100000000)
df = 
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Mazaeva...Результат.csv',sep = 
';',encoding="UTF-8", engine='python')
df.columns = ['Num', 'Link','Text','State','All']
docids = list(df['Link'])   
corpus = [txtpreproceesor(Text).split(' ') for Text in df['Text'] if Text 
not in stopWords]

dtm = shorttext.utils.DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, docids=docids, tfidf=False)
dtm.get_doc_tokens('http://17cpis.ru')
```

В итоге имеем неожиданно в итоговом списке слова : "а", "и", "о" и т.д. Никаких ошибок не выдается, но список stopWords явно не применяется.
Не могу понять что не так.
[image: Data Frame]

[image: stopWords]

[image: Result]

Comment: Наверное дело в том, что `if Text not in stopWords` проверяет наличие всей строки в `stopWords`, но не отдельных слов.

Comment: можете привести небольшой пример (в виде текста, который можно скопировать) данных из столбца `df['Text']` содержащий `stopwords`? Ещё попробуйте заменить `txtpreproceesor(Text).split(' ')` --> `txtpreproceesor(Text).split()`

Comment: Заменить попробовала, не помогает. Вы можете взять кусочек датасета тут (https://yadi.sk/d/MFYT-xy8r8JBww)

Comment: @Mar'yaMazaeva, я не хочу устанавливать дополнительные модули (shorttext), поэтому попросил часть уже обработанного текста...

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в несвоевременной фильтрации. Перенос в пайплайн спас положение.
`lambda s: ' '.join(i for i in s.split() if i not in stopWords)`
Всем спасибо.